# Set empty cell in the middle of android GridView layout

Tags: android, gridview

I working on my project with gridview layout, and the whole code is pretty identical to Android Developers example (I can't post links because of my low reputation, sorry).

Its works fantastic, when I need to fill screen with 3*3 or 4*4 (and etc) grids, but now I have to design my gridview with only 8 imageviews and I want to set the empty cell in the middle of GridView, just like that (click for images):

That is my current position:

[image: current position]

This is what I need to do:

[image: need to do]

I have googled that a lot, but I can't find some example that shows how to implement that. 
Have you any idea how can I solve that issue?

Set it to invisible -

```
imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

not works for me, because then I "lost" one of my imageViews.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Create a transparent middle image!

Comment: Do you have always 7 items on your GridView? Or (x*x)-1 items?

Comment: Hey @NguyenDoanTung, I have edited my question. Can You check it again? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Let's consider you will always have an `(x*x)` number of items in your `GridView`,  where `x` is an odd number bigger than 1, like 3 or 5. The index of the item that you want to hide is `items.size()/2`. Note that in Android, 9/2 = 4 and 25/2 = 12. So, we already know the index of the item that should be hidden.

Following, in the code, you just have to make your item `View` stay invisible when that your `adapter.getView()` method is called for that index. Here is that `getView()` portion of the code:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    LayoutInflater inflater = yourContext.getLayoutInflater();

    if(convertView==null)
    {

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_grid_item_layout, null);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }
    else
    {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    if(position == yourItemsList.size()/2){
        convertView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        convertView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    return convertView;

}
```

This will make your middle `View` invisible. The effect that you wanted.

Also note that your `GridView` number of lines has to be equal to the number of rows for this method to work.

You can always change the number of rows dynamically, according to the number of items that you have. In your `Activity` code, before `gridView.setAdapter()`, like this:

```
    gridView.setNumColumns((int) Math.sqrt(myItemsList.size()));
```

Again I warn you that this code only works for `GridView` configurations of 3*3, 5*5, 7*7, and so on.

Comment: Hey @joao2fast4u! Sorry for that long response, I have a difficult exams period. I have edited my original post, can You check it again please? I stuck with that for a while... Very appreciate you for the help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try to implement my solution?

Comment: Yes. When I implement with `(View.INVISIBLE)` the adapter takes imageview from my imageviews array and set him to invisible. But in that case I "lost" my imageview. Because each of them is different. What I need is, that the adapter will pass (or not take) imageview when position == 5 (for example). Look at the 2 images that I attached to the question, it's the best explanation. Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: Actually this is a simple memory game, so the size of the gridview is depends on level. its starts with 3*3 and going to 7*6. The number of imageviews in an array is depends and changes at every level.

Comment: And how would you hide the middle cell in a 7*6 layout if there is no middle cell?

Comment: In 7*6 gridview I don't need to hide the middle cell. But in 3*3 I do. Have you any idea how can adapter pass over and make one of the cells empty? Thanks again!

Comment: Could't you just add an empty item in the middle of your array, so it can be hidden in your `getView()` method?